# extJS setValue on a TextField weird problems

Tags: extjs, textfield, setvalue

I'm using an xtype of textfield, and of course gave an id so I can reference this. And I want to set the value of the textfield when choosing something from a drop down list. The way I set the value is below:

Ext.getCmp('textfieldId).setValue(variableDropDown);

So here is where things get weird. I can choose stuff off a drop down and have it populate the textfield. After maybe 10 or more times, or if I revisit the page and do it again, the textfield fails to update. I set an alert box and saw the item I chose off the list was indeed the correct value...just the textfield isn't updating...

ANy ideas?

Comment: Please add a minimum (non-)working example.

Comment: Are you using `comboBox.getValue()` to get the selected value from the `combobox`?

Comment: can you please paste your code?

Answer (score 0):

May be try some like

```js
var variableDropDown = Ext.getCmp('cmbFieldId').getValue();
Ext.getCmp('textfieldId').setValue(variableDropDown);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vinodgubbala/hCvW5/